# how to delete data from a delta file in databricks?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I want to delete data from a delta file in databricks.
Im using these commands
Ex:

```
PR=spark.read.format('delta').options(header=True).load('/mnt/landing/Base_Tables/EventHistory/')
PR.write.format("delta").mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('PR')
spark.sql('delete from PR where PR_Number=4600')
```

This is deleting data from the table but not from the actual delta file. And i want to delete the data in the file without using merge operation, because the join condition is not matching. Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please do remember : Subqueries are not supported in the DELETE in Delta.

Issue Link : https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/730

From the documentation itself , an Alternative is as follows

For Example :

```
DELETE FROM tdelta.productreferencedby_delta 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT KEY 
              FROM   delta.productreferencedby_delta_dup_keys) 
       AND srcloaddate <= '2020-04-15'
```

Can be written as below in case of DELTA

```
MERGE INTO delta.productreferencedby_delta AS d 
using (SELECT KEY FROM   tdatamodel_delta.productreferencedby_delta_dup_keys) AS k 
ON d.id = k.KEY 
  AND d.srcloaddate <= '2020-04-15' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Spark SQL functions in python would be:

```
dt_path = "/mnt/landing/Base_Tables/EventHistory/"
my_dt = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, dt_path)
seq_keys = ["4600"] // You could add here as many as you want
my_dt.delete(col("PR_Number").isin(seq_keys))
```

And in scala:

```
val dt_path = "/mnt/landing/Base_Tables/EventHistory/"
val my_dt : DeltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, dt_path)
val seq_keys = Seq("4600") // You could add here as many as you want
my_dt.delete(col("PR_Number").isin(seq_keys:_*))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove data that matches a predicate from a Delta table
https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#delete-from-a-table

Answer (score 0):

It worked like

```
delete from delta.`/mnt/landing/Base_Tables/EventHistory/` where PR_Number=4600
```

Comment: previously you where try to save as a managed table, to store in the external location you need to mention the path as well

Comment: PR.write.format("delta").option('path', 'your mount path') .mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('PR')

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already figured, you need to run a `VACCUM` operation over the table in order to delete the physical data files. Just the `DELETE` operation followed by a `VACCUM` operation should be sufficient for your usecase.